# CNN Semantic segmentation network (UNET) performing poorly when tested with images

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision

I am working on building a UNET semantic segmentation network, to detect the iris in eye images we are using DICE loss function and we achieved over 90% train mean IOU and around 87% on validation data but the validation loss and mean IOU showed fluctuation during the 200 epochs, and when we tested our network it showed really poor results, the output image was nothing close to the ground truth even when we used images from the training set it still performed poorly, any suggestions on what we can do to overcome this.

Comment: We're likely going to need more information than this, see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Is the dataset public? You can find some good resources and guidance here: `https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/tree/master/TensorFlow2/Segmentation/UNet_Medical` you will find also benchmark results. I think they are usinf ADAM optimizer with 0.0001 learning rate. More details in the training process section.

Comment: We tested out with a 0.0001 learning rate but it gave us really poor results, even though the mean_iou was high

Answer (score 0):

What does your implementation of the DSC Loss look like? And what is the activation function you're using? I've personally used:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-3):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    dice = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return dice

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

as the loss function and metric in several U-Net segmentation architectures, and sigmoid as the activation function (assuming it's a binary classification problem). Also, if you're optimizing for IOU, you may want to change your loss to be an IOU loss - something along the lines of:

```
def iou(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-3):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    union = K.sum((y_true,-1) + K.sum(y_pred,-1) - intersection
    return (intersection + smooth) / ( union + smooth)

def iou_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -iou_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I am using for dice:
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    intersection = k.sum(k.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (k.sum(k.square(y_true),-1) + k.sum(k.square(y_pred),-1) + smooth)


def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)

so you think I should use mean_IOU as both loss function and metric

Comment: Yes - if you want to optimize for IOU, it makes sense that your model would be configured with an IOU-based loss function. Is it a multiclass segmentation problem or binary class?

Comment: it's a binary class problem

Comment: and is it possible that the network is too deep, we are also using dropouts and batchnorm, what other parameters you think we can adjust